# How to hide a label for="x01" checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to hide this checkbox, which is a check all checkbox in my table header, using jQuery but am not having much luck.

The view source of the section I am trying to hide from the user is as follows:

```
<th class="t12subheader" id="CHECK$01"><label for="x01" class="hideMe508">Check All</label><input type="checkbox" name="x02" value="1" onclick="checkAll(this)" /></th>
```

I have tried both:

```
$('#x01, label[for="x01"]').hide ();  &
$('#x01').hide ();
```

to no avail.

Also, does it matter the positioning of hiding this checkbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your label hiding is ok, however the checkbox won't work since it doesn't have `id="x01"`, at least in your pasted code.  It *does* have `name="x02"` so you can find/hide it via that, like this:

```
$('input[name="x02"], label[for="x01"]').hide();​
```

I'm guessing you meant the label to go with the input, in which case the checkbox should have a matching `id` to the label's `for`, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="x01" name="x02" value="1" onclick="checkAll(this)" />
```

Then your selector would be:

```
$('#x01, label[for="x01"]').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks all and thanks to you Nick - your first method worked.

Answer (score 0):

the `for` attribute doesn't count as an id. Give your label it's own id, something like "x01_label", and then you can easily hide it.

Your first attempt might work if you remove the #x01, from it. There's nothing in your code sample with an id of `x01`. Just select `label[for="x01"]`. If not then try the id thing instead.

Comment: The first is a multiple selector, it should resolve elements that match selectors separated by the `,` -- so removing the `#x01,` from it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

From the code it seems you are trying to hide the label. Do this  `$("label.hideme508").hide()`;
No idea what is the  class `hideme508`, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#CHECK$01,label[for="x01"]').hide();` should work. your `label` is child of `CHECK$01` and not `x01`